# Gin AssistedInject: Deferred binding result type 'Foo' should not be abstract

Tags: java, gwt, dependency-injection, gwt-gin, assisted-inject

I'm trying to use AssistedInject with Gin in GWT 2.4.0:

```
  public interface ElevatorButtonFactory {
    ElevatorButton create(int shownFloorNumber, Action<Integer> onClick);
  }

  @Inject
  ElevatorButton(GameHost gameHost, @Assisted int shownFloorNumber,
      @Assisted Action<Integer> onClick) {
    // ...
  }
```

In my Gin module:

```
install(new GinFactoryModuleBuilder().implement(ElevatorButton.class, ElevatorButton.class)
        .build(ElevatorButtonFactory.class));
```

That seems like it should be sufficient, right? But when I try to take `ElevatorButtonFactory` as an injected parameter, I get the following error:

> [ERROR] [foo] - Deferred binding result type
>   'com.foo.html.client.components.floorpicker.ElevatorButton.ElevatorButtonFactory'
>   should not be abstract

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like that problem is not about GIN. It's about how do you use your `ElevatorButtonFactory` class. Your injector interface should look like this:

```
@GinModules(YourGinModule.class)
public interface InjectorService extends Ginjector {

    ElevatorButtonFactory getElevatorButtonFactory();

}
```

Create `ElevatorButton` instance:

```
GWT.create(InjectorService.class).getElevatorButtonFactory().create(...)
```

May be you try to instantiate your factory via GWT.create() or something else? If the problem will not gone - let me look at the full stacktrace.